# Get Nth type of variadic template **when one or more of the types is an interface**

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm needing to index in to a variadic template to get the Nth type, but I am unable to use `std::tuple` since I cannot guarantee that all types won't be abstract. For example, the line:

```
using Type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Types...>>::type;
```

Gives compilation errors when one or more of `Types` is abstract (e.g. an interface). Is there a different way of indexing a variadic template using the STL? This isn't a difficult problem to solve:

```
template <size_t Index, typename... Types>
struct get_type;

template <typename Type, typename... Types>
struct get_type<0, Type, Types...>
{
    using type = Type;
};

template <size_t Index, typename Type, typename... Types>
struct get_type<Index, Type, Types...>
{
    using type = typename get_type<Index - 1, Types...>::type;
};
```

But I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if the standard provides an alternate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `std::tuple` (your template alias is working), it simply is that you cannot declare an *object* of abstract type, you need to declare a pointer or a reference to it.

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... Types>
using Type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Types...>>::type;

struct X
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;   
};

int main(){
   Type<0, int, double, X> t1;
   Type<1, int, double, X> t2;
   Type<2, int, double, X>* t3;  // We declare a X*
};
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a63c92e8bdea05a6)

Comment: After being unable to repro this in a new project, I debugged it a bit more and found out that the other project is using an older STL version. Time to go cry in a hole... :(